# Entity Framework 5 on SQL Server 2019, after an insert error (validation error) I can't insert any record

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have a program downloading data and saving into my SQL Server 2019 database. The program uses Entity Framework 5, and saves hundreds of rows in a lot of tables.

When the downloaded data causes an error (for example a string is longer than the database column), I get an exception and can't save the row. And this is ok.

The bad thing is that if the saving of the row #100 fails, every subsequent row also throws the same error. Currently I create a `DbContext` at the beginning of the program, and I don't use transactions.

I tried with `TransactionScope`, with the same results: the following rows aren't getting saved.

Can someone help me understand WHY after an error I can't save any more rows?